# Django Import-Export Importing with User object failing

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-import-export

I am attempting to import data using the Import-Export library.
I have a User foreign key in my model called creator, and rather than referencing the pk of the User i want to use usernames. But when i try to import the data it fails

Some other Stack posts have suggested adding a skip feature, or creating a custom widget that queries the database first but that is also not working.

## model

```
class MediaEntry(models.Model):
    media_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=increment, editable=False)
    media_designation = models.ForeignKey(MediaDesignation, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_used_or_received = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

## resources

```
from import_export import resources, fields, widgets
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from .models import BlankMedia, MediaLocations, AuditLocation, MediaType,  MediaEntry
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MediaEntryResource(resources.ModelResource):

    creator = fields.Field(
        column_name='creator',
        attribute='creator',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(model=User, field='username')
    )
   
    class Meta:
        model = MediaEntry
        fields = ('id', 'media_number', 'creator',)
```

## Admin

```
from .resources import BlankMediaResource, MediaLocationResource, MediaTypeResource, AuditLocationResource,MediaEntryResource
class MediaEntryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = MediaEntryResource
```

If the code worked it should preview the imported values but it fails with NOT NULL constraint failed: medialog_mediaentry.creator_id

Comment: Have you figured this out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: No unfortunately I never did I ended up working around it by creating my own import method, but I no longer have access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register your admin in admin.py?

```
from import_export import resources, fields, widgets
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from .models import BlankMedia, MediaLocations, AuditLocation, MediaType,  MediaEntry
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MediaEntryResource(resources.ModelResource):

    creator = fields.Field(
        column_name='creator_id',
        attribute='creator_id',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(model=User, field='username')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MediaEntry
        fields = ('id', 'media_number', 'creator',)
```

```
from .resources import BlankMediaResource, MediaLocationResource, MediaTypeResource, AuditLocationResource,MediaEntryResource

class MediaEntryAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = MediaEntryResource

admin.site.register(MediaEntry, MediaEntryAdmin)
```

Comment: I do have that yes.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check and try again.
replace: column_name = "creator" to column_name="creator_id"
attribute="creator" to attribute="creator_id"

Comment: Not sure if fixed but new error is "Line number: 1 - 'id'" and field = self.resource.fields[key]
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: Can you post the exact error while using column_name="creator"?